# How to handle secured API in service to service communication

Tags: api, authentication, architecture, authorization, microservices

I have a working monolith application (deployed in a container), for which I want to add notifications feature as a separate microservice.

I'm planning for the monolith to emit events to a message bus (RabbitMQ) where they will be received by the new service, which will send the notification to user. In order to compose a notification, it will need other information about the user from the monolit, so it will call monolith's REST API in order to obtain it.

The problem is, that access to the monolith's API requires authentication in form of a token. I was thinking of:

- using the secret from the monolith to issue a never-expiring token - I don't think this is a great idea from the security perspective, and also I know that sometimes the keys rotate in which case the token would became invalid eventually anyway
- using the message bus to retrieve the information - this does not seem a good idea either as the asynchrony would make it very complicated
- providing all the info the notification service needs in the event - this would make them more coupled together, and moreover, I plan to also send notifications based on the state on the monolith not triggered by an event
- removing the authentication from the monolith and implementing it differently (not sure how yet)

My question is, what are some of the good ways this kind of problem can be solved, and also, having just started learning about microservices, is what I am trying to do right in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with internal security you should always consider the deployment and how the APIs are exposed to the outside world, an API gateway might be used to simply make it impossible to access internal APIs. In that case, a fixed token might be good enough to ensure that the client is authorized.

In general, though, I would suggest looking into OAuth2 or a JWT-based solution as it helps to validate the identities of the calling system as well as their access grants.

As for your architecture doubts, you need to consider the following scenarios when building out the solution:

1. The remote call can fail, at any time for unknown reasons, as such you shouldn't acknowledge the notification event until you're certain that the notification has been processed successfully.
2. As you've mentioned RabbitMQ, you should aim to keep the notification queue as small as possible, to that effect, a cache that contains the user details might help speed things along (and help you reduce the chance of failure due to the external system not being available).
3. If your application sends a lot of notifications to potentially millions of different users, you could consider having a read-only database replica of the users which is accessible to the notification service, and directly read from the database cluster in batches. This reduces the load on the monolith and shift it to the database layer